# echo $_POST['code']; error in google chrome

Tags: php, html, google-chrome

I have one page where I submit hidden form where I store a large html code that is made in javascript and I want to send that code via form to another php file. It should work but my browser blocks it(google chrome):

```
<form action="napravi.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="code" value=""/>
<input type="submit" id="forma_napravi"/>
</form>
```

and in javascript:

```
document.getElementById("forma_napravi").click();
```

and php page where I send the form data:

```
if(isset($_POST['code'])){
echo $_POST['code'];
}
```

and this is error that browser shows to me:

[image]

Comment: Any js action where it is possible to have cross site access?

Comment: @Eakethet I have only html in code, the only thing that might trigger it is onclick="function()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will show error if you send html or javascript code this way because it is google chrome's in-built design.

I tried your code it was working. But when I put some code in place of blank, e.g. `value="<script>alert('123');</script>"`, I got the same error

[image]

You may use htmlentities() to parse the html to string. Then the code you send will have no effect at all.

Comment: Thanks, I have no javascript in that code only html but I have `<div onclick="function"></div>` I think that was the problem, I found out about `header('X-XSS-Protection:0');` and It works now, as it is not important, does not contain any passwords or anything I might use it, but your solution is safer and better, so I thank you

Answer (score 0):

give your form an id and check if it is been submitted. like this-

**In your html file**

```
<form action="napravi.php" method="post" id="form">
  <input type="text" name="code" value=""/>
  <input type="submit" id="forma_napravi"/>
</form>
```

**In your javascript**

```
document.getElementById("form").on('submit', function(){
   // your code
});
```

Hope this will help

Comment: when I submit form it navigates to new page("napravi.php"), so where should I put that javascript code? in "napravi.php"?